# Что происходит в websocketHandler'е в данном случае?

Tags: java, vert.x

Работая с vert.x core 3.2.1 увидел такую конфигурацию сервера, использующего веб-соккет:

```
vertx.createHttpServer().websocketHandler(ws -> ws.handler(ws::writeBinaryMessage)).requestHandler(req -> {
            if (req.uri().equals("/")) req.response().sendFile("ws.html");
        }).listen(8080);
```

По записи я понял,что на платформе вертекса мы создаем http-сервер который с помощью метода listen,слушающего порт 8080 находится в ожидании возможного  к нему подключения. Также тут используется вебсокетный хендлер, который связан с request-хендлером. Но четкого понимания о том,что происходит в websocketHandler нет. Лямбда-выражения и ::-оператор меня запутали. Объясните пожалуйста что исполняет данный код, или если возможно,распишите эту конструкцию без лямбд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После проб и ошибок,вроде бы удалось привести это заклинание с лямбдами к более простому и громоздкому виду:

```
server.websocketHandler(ws -> ws.handler(ws::writeBinaryMessage))
                .requestHandler(req -> { if (req.uri().equals("smile")) req.response().end("hello");});

        server.websocketHandler(new Handler<ServerWebSocket>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ServerWebSocket webs) {
                webs.writeBinaryMessage(Buffer.buffer());
            }
        }).requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
                             @Override
                             public void handle(HttpServerRequest req) {
                                 if (req.uri().equals("smile")) req.response().end("hello");
                             }
                         });
```

В итоге видим следующее:первый хендлер в данном туториале работает с веб-сокетным соединением и в нем можно осуществлять обмен сообщениями, второй хендлер предназначен для работы с http и выводит в браузер "hello". Таким образом вертекс предоставляет набор интерфейсов(хендлеров),которые позволяют работать с соединениями различного типа.