# Информация о Vert.x и VUI

Tags: vert.x

Что такое Vert.x и VUI?
Если можно, опишите более подробно.

Comment: Не знаю как кому, но для меня странно когда человек задает вопрос, а потом никак не реагирует. Какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 5):

**Vert.x** это событийно-ориентированный фреймворк работающий на JVM. На данный момент последняя версия этого фреймворка 3.5.

[Официальный сайт](http://vertx.io/)
[Официальный блог](http://vertx.io/blog/)
[Vert.x  в Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vert.x)
[Vert.x на Habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=Vert.x#h)
[Руководство по эксплуатации на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRFwicUlwyI&list=PLVe-2wcL84b8x3krxqsYHwlmfb4kb8A4n&index=14)

**VUI** (Visual User Interface) - визуальный (трёхмерный) интерфейс пользователя.

**VUI** (Voice User Interface) - (`"голосовой интерфейс"` или `"голосовой интерфейс пользователя"`) при помощи голосовой\речевой платформы делает возможным взаимодействие человека и компьютера для запуска автоматизированного сервиса или процесса.

[Про VUI в Wikipedia на русском](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)
[Будущее голосового дизайна](http://uxgu.ru/future-of-vui/)
[VUI на Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/vui)

#### Литература

[Майкл Коэн "Дизайн голосового пользовательского интерфейса"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=PI_n2EcJfT0C&hl=en&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

#### Вопросы по Vert.x на ru.Stackoverflow

[Что происходит в методе newInstance?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513378/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-newinstance)
[Что происходит в websocketHandler'е в данном случае?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508462/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b2-websockethandler%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5)
[Как установить route на http-сервере при websocket-соединении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510345/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-route-%d0%bd%d0%b0-http-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-websocket-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)
[Что означает метод route() и его параметры в данном случае?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510007/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-route-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5)
[Как правильно прописать отправку сообщения клиенту с сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)