# Есть ли документация по Vert.x на русском?

Tags: vert.x

Начал изучать Vert.x. Подскажите, где можно найти документацию или хороший туториал по Vert.x на русском?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771960/262779

Comment: Да и ссылок на литературу довольно много в ответе L.F.C.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771971/243186

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Информация о Vert.x и VUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771960/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-vert-x-%d0%b8-vui)

Comment: VUI - это не то, что мне нужно. На сайте Vert.x очень мало примеров, хотелось бы найти туториал на русском или хотя бы на английском.

Comment: При чем тут VUI? Там есть ряд ссылок на ресурсы по Vert.x, в том числе на русском. Доки вообще лучше на английском изучать, так как делая не так, будете всегда как отстающий вагон. Переводы прилетают спустя 2 года, а технология меняется\обновляется.

Comment: @L.F.C. да, я уже читаю статьи на хабре. А также у них на сайте нашел небольшие мануалы по java и Javadoc документацию, буду изучать постепенно, слишком маленький Community у этого фреймворка. Благодарю за помощь!